# 2 equations, 3 unknown variables, 1 common variable in both. Can any variable be solved?

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

Given:
$$61 = (35 + 90x) / a$$
$$610 = (1000 + 20000x) / b$$

Is there a way to determine a value of a, b, and/or x?

It seems like, if I could somehow calculate $a*x$ and $b*x$, perhaps by moving them to a side by themselves, I can narrow down x to be one of their common divisors.

$$a*x = 300$$
$$b*x = 15$$

```
Common Divisors Of 300 and 15 = 15, 5, 1, 3 <-- value of x
```

I can't seem to re-arrange the equation to produce this effect though.

What is the best way to solve for a, b, and/or x? Examples please, my math is a bit rusty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you write about common divisors, I assume that $a$, $b$, and $x$ are all meant to be integers. After some minor simplifications, you have:

$$61a = 35+90x\\
61b = 100+2000x$$

Working modulo $61$ both $a$ and $b$ will drop out of the equations:

$$0 = 35+90x \mod 61\\
0 = 100+2000x \mod 61$$

From the second of these we get:
$$0 = 1+20x \mod 61\\
0 = 3+60x \mod 61\\
-60x = 3 \mod 61\\
x = 3 \mod 61$$

Luckily $x=3$ is also a solution to the first modular equation ($35+90*3=305=5*61$ so it is $0$ modulo $61$), so the two equations are compatible.

So now we know that $x=61k+3$ for some integer $k$. If you substitute that into the original equations, you get $a = 90k+5$ and $b = 2000k+100$. So for any integer value of $k$, you have the solution:
$$(a,b,x) = (90k+5, 2000k+100, 61k+3)$$

Comment: I think I need to learn a bit more about modular math. It seems like you were able to solve for x about 3/4 of the way through. Two questions. 1) Was both equations necessary to derive x or was one enough? 2) Does everything here still work with the following adjustments to the second equation? Same x, different b. 61=(35+90x)/a, and 25=(100+50x)/b. I tried to apply your steps with this equation set and got stuck probably because it doesn't simplify with the same mod value.

Comment: The original two equations turned out to be identical mod $61$, so from the equation with $a$ you will still get that $x=61k+3$ for some $k$, otherwise $a$ won't be an integer. Your new equation for $b$ simplifies to $b=2(x+2)$, which is an integer for every integer value of $x$, so it does not impose any further restrictions on $x$, though as you can see, $b$ will be even. So you get $(a,b,x)=(90k+4, 2(61k+5), 61k+3)$.

Comment: A typo - that should have been $(a,b,x)=(90k+5,\ 2(61k+5),\ 61k+3)$.